# I want to apply Except between two lists. One list is in MailAddress format and other is a String (Converted to list))

Tags: c#, linq, mailaddress

I want to apply `Except` between two lists. One list is in `MailAddress` format and other is a `String` (Converted to list))?

```
         List<MailAddress> toemails = new List<MailAddress>();
            //List<String> emailsFrom = address.Split(';').ToList();
            List<string> temp1 = new List<string>();
            List<MailAddress> temp2 = new List<MailAddress>();
            List<MailAddress> temp3 = new List<MailAddress>();

      //message.to gives me a list of messages (outgoing)
            foreach (var e in message.To)
            {
                temp2.Add(e);
            }

           //result contains a list of emails fetched (count=7)
            var result = from lst in ListofEmails where lst.ToLower().Length < 50 select lst;
            temp1 = result.ToList();

            //(Not able to understand this, how to proceed)

            // toemails = temp2.Except(temp1.);
            // MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
```

The output, result of `Except`, should be a list of `MailAddress` objects.

Comment: What kind of properties are you hoping to search for in order to exclude from `temp2` ? You obviously can't use `temp2` as a class because you'd be comparing `List<MailAddres>` to `List<string>`.

Comment: can you describe your problem properly

Comment: You need to either iterate over temp1 and create a new list of MailAddress objects (im assuming contain a property for email address, which is what you seem to be comparing), or you can do a .Select on temp2 to make a new list of string values (email address). Then do your except, because you will have two lists of the same type.

Comment: So basically i am extracting a list of email addresses from database and storing them in list format. Message.to contains all email address which are in "To".    I want to use Except so that i will get rid of those emails from To which are already present in the list extracted from database. (Description) @sayahimad

Comment: @BioSafety- can you help with the select query, not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use Except, just use basic LINQ:

Since temp1 contains the e-mail addresses...

```
toemails = temp2.Where(email =>
          !temp1.Any(e => e.Equals(email.Address, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```